# Trouble in connecting expo app with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

FirebaseConnect.js

```
import firebase from "firebase";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};
let app;
if (firebase.apps.length===0){
    app=firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}else{
    app=firebase.app();
}
const auth = firebase.auth();

export {auth};
```

This is the file I have created to provide authentication to the react native app. When I run npm run android I encounter the error:

> Unable to resolve "firebase" from "firebaseConnect.js"

I followed the steps as per the docs at https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#using-firebase-js-sdk

Please suggest ways to fix this error and connect firebase services with a react native expo app